# Confusion with lifecycle methods - why is my API call not returning data?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, lifecycle

I'm building a bar website using react, which requires me to fetch information about beers on tap. I'm retrieving that information from `http://www.hashigozake.co.nz/taplist.xml` and as you can see, the data is being return in XML format. This data is then converted to a js object using a libary called xml-react-parser.

Anyway, I've written the following code to make this API call:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://www.hashigozake.co.nz/taplist.xml'
        const proxyURL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
      
        fetch(proxyURL + url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(beerXML => {
          let beerJs = new XMLParser().parseFromString(beerXML)
          this.setState({
            beers: beerJs
          })

        })
      }
```

So here's where the problem is. I'm passing the taplist data (`{beerList =this.state.beers}`) as props to another component called `TileList.jsx`. In this component, I'm running the following console log:
`console.log(props.beerList.children[0])` which should return an array of objects, but instead, is giving me a error message, saying  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

What I suspect is happening is that the render() method is being called before the fetch() method has finished returning the data, which is why I get an `undefined` when I try and access my data. I'm confused because I thought that componenentDidMount was triggered after the render method, so shouldn't all my data be rendered?

Anyway, here's a more detailed look at my code:

Parent component: `Home.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import hashi_logo_2 from './Photos/hashi_logo_2.png'
import TileList from './TileList'
import OnNextList from './OnNextList'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
const XMLParser = require('react-xml-parser')

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            beers:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://www.hashigozake.co.nz/taplist.xml'
        const proxyURL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
      
        fetch(proxyURL + url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(beerXML => {
          let beerJs = new XMLParser().parseFromString(beerXML)
          this.setState({
            beers: beerJs
          })

        })
      }

    render() {
    return (
        <div className = 'home'>
            <nav className = 'nav'>
                <ul>
                    <Link to = '/about' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} >
                        <li className='list'>About</li>
                    </Link>
                    <li className='list'>Food</li>
                    <li className='list'>Events</li>
                    <li className='list'>News</li>
                    <Link to ='/shop' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} >
                        <li className='list'>Shop</li>
                    </Link>
                    <li className='list'>Contact</li>
                    <li className='list'>Blog</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <main>
                <div className='main__image'>
                    <img src= {hashi_logo_2}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <TileList beerList = {this.state.beers}/>
                    <OnNextList/>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Home
```

Child component: `TileList.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import Tile from './Tile'

const TileList = (props) => {
    console.log(props.beerList.children[0])
    return (
        <>
         <h1 className = 'h1-pouring'>Currently Pouring:</h1> 
        <div className = 'tile-container'>
            {
                props.beerList.map(item => {
                    return <Tile 
                    />
                })
            } 
        </div> 
        </>
    )
}

export default TileList
```

Also, here's a (incomplete) view of the data being sent as props:

```
{
  name: 'Products', attributes:{}, value:'', children: [
    {
      name:'Beers', attributes: {}, value: '', children: [
        {
          name: 'Product', attributes:{}, value:'', children: {
            
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `this.state.beerList` ***IS*** the empty array, that is the initial state. You shouldn't change your state shape. Did you intend to make initial state an empty object? Also, as such with initial state, you'll need to use guards and check that `props.beerList.children` exists before trying to access array indices.

Comment: Hey @DrewReese, thanks for the feedback. ```props.beerList.children``` is returning the data I want. The problem is that when I try accessing data that is deeper in the structure, for example ```props.beerList.children[0]```, I get the undefined warning in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Your initial state doesn't provide enough of the data structure to be able to correctly access more deeply.

The `beers` object is defined initially as an empty array in `Home`

```
this.state = {
  beers: [],
}
```

And passed as prop to `TileList`

```
<TileList beerList={this.state.beers} /> // this.state.beers ~ []
```

Within `TileList` you try to immediately log more deeply

```
console.log(props.beerList.children[0]);
```

Examining this, `props.beerList` is currently the empty array (`[]`) with no property of `children`, i.e. `props.beerList.children` or `props.beerList['children']` is undefined, so trying to access an index `0` will throw error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

#### Secondary Issue

Initial state is `beers = []`, but later the response shape is an object

```
{
  name: 'Products', attributes:{}, value:'', children: [
    {
      name:'Beers', attributes: {}, value: '', children: [
        {
          name: 'Product', attributes:{}, value:'', children: {
            
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This inconsistent state type can make it more difficult to debug code, or in other words, makes it easier to have buggy code.

## Solution

Keep state type consistent.

```
this.state = {
  beers: {},
}
```

Use guards or optional chaining to check first

```
props.beerList.children &&
props.beerList.children.length && 
console.log(props.beerList.children[0]);
```

or

```
console.log(props.beerList?.children?.[0]);
```

Access the correct nested property for mapping the beers

```
props.beerList.children &&
props.beerList.children.length && 
props.beerList.children[0].children && 
props.beerList.children[0].children.map(product => ...
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, that fixed it! I'm new to the concept of guards but it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @JoshSimon Yes, the Guard Pattern, is common enough, but as you can see, is also a little bulky. Before optional chaining, in my code if I needed to go more than a couple guards deep into an object I'd just try direct access and surround with a try/catch. This isn't useful, however, when trying to map to JSX in the render function. Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

According to the react doc [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), setState is async, in the first render,  props.beerList is an empty array, then setState() will trigger a second render so you can get value by index in the second render if your return contains a value.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
> right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
> componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
> callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
> has been applied.